# Converting dates from different centuries

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I have staging table which contains date as string with format 'mm/dd/yy'. I have Oracle 11g procedure to convert the string to date format before loading into main table. I'm using `to_date('03/20/34','mm/dd/rr')` to convert into date format which is giving wrong output as 03/20/2034 whereas the correct date is 03/20/1934. Please help me out to get the correct output where my table contains dates from both centuries.

Comment: default date conversion adds first 2 digits of the current year to the date format. If you want year 34 to be treated as 1934 in stead of 2034, you have to append 19 before 34.

Comment: Did you try to_date('03/20/1934','mm/dd/rrrr') ?

Comment: @Debabrata My data source will always have 'mm/dd/yy' date format so if i use to_date('03/20/34','mm/dd/rrrr'), it will get me same wrong date.

Comment: @kraj, how do you know that the year 34 is 1934 not 2034. So there should be some flag/mechanism to let the compiler know that its 1934 not 2034.

Comment: @Debabrata "default date conversion adds first 2 digits of the current year to the date format" - that's not quite right. A format that uses `RR` for the year (e.g., the default nls_date_format of 'DD-MON-RR') will (as of today) return a century of 19 if the last two digits of the year are between 50 and 99, and 20 if they are between 00 and 49.

Comment: Thanx for the update @Boneist. I Didn't know about that.

Comment: Classic [Year 2000 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) - but I am really surprised that it still happens in 2017. Did you not discover this error for 17 years?

Answer (score 2):

> "I'm using to_date('03/20/34','mm/dd/rr') to convert into date format which is giving wrong output as 03/20/2034 whereas the correct date is 03/20/1934. "

`RR` was a hack Oracle introduced in the last Millennium as part of the fight to resolve [the Y2K bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem). The standard date mask `YY` defaults the century to the current century. But in 1999 it was more likely that `01/01/00` meant `01/01/2000` rather than `01/01/1900`. So the `RR` hack was to derive the century for dates using fixed windows pivoting on `00`: values 00-49 are given century `20`, 50-99 are given `19`. Clearly some of the time this guess would be wrong, but the data corruption introduced was of a lower level than defaulting all dates to century `19`.

The key point is, the windows are fixed. It was intended to be a temporary solution, because there wasn't time to switch all the legacy systems to use four-digit years before 2000 arrived. But the vision was always that all systems would be fixed in the long term, even if only through retirement or replacement. Certainly nobody expected that new systems would be built supporting two-digit years.

It is now **2017** and there is no excuse for systems to still be using two-digit years. Back in the old days storage was expensive, and shaving two digits from a date was a valuable space saving. Now it is just sloppiness.

Which obviously doesn't help you solve your problem. The short answer is there is no way to change the pivot used by `RR`. The best solution would be to enforce stricter validation on the data input aspect of your system, and insist on four-digit years. Whether that's feasible depends on your office politics. The other solution is to write your own conversion function:

```
 create or replace function my_to_date (p_str varchar2) return date as
 begin
     if to_number(substr(p_str, 7) <= 35 then
         return to_date(substr(p_str, 1, 6)||'19'||substr(p_str, 7), 'dd/mm/yyyy');
     else
         return to_date(substr(p_str, 1, 6)||'20'||substr(p_str, 7), 'dd/mm/yyyy');
 end;
```

Obviously you'll need to define the actual rules for deciding whether to use `19` or `20`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will go with the data source correction to 4 digit year so that my process logic remains good irrespective of year.

Comment: @kraj, don't just change the data source to store 4 digit years in a string - instead, use Oracle's builtin `DATE` datatype.

Comment: Thanks for the historical background information as well as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered an issue like this, when inserting date values from the late 90s. The format in the script I was given read DD-MON-YY, so the database read that as 20YY, instead of 19YY.

My very inelegant solution was to open the raw data file and simply add a "19" before the YY year values.