# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis -- Strange

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the error " ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" but I've checked and all the parenthesis are there, so I'm stumped.

Am getting this error while using Select Statement. Please help. I need to use the Between to_date also to fetch the data between two particular dates.

```
select

 DT.ARRIVAL||','||
 DT.LOCATION_CODE||','|| nvl (decode (
                                 DT.OWNER_FLAG, 'R', 'B', 'M', 'B',
                              DT.OWNER_FLAG), 'B') OWNER_FLAG,
 DT.RECEIPT||','||
 PP.BILL_NUMBER||','||
 DT.TRANSPORT_MODE||','||
 substr (TRANSPORT_NAME,1,20)
               , TRANSPORT_TYPE||','||
 PP.PRODUCT||','||
 AP.PRODUCT_NAME||','||
 AP.PRODUCT_QTY||','||
 AP.PRODUCT_QTY_Units||','||
 DT.INSPECTOR||','||
 AP.PRODUCT_NO||','||
 AP.PRODUCT_FLAG||','||
 PP.BILL_STATUS
 from BILL_PARCEL PP,
 PRODUCT DT,
 SUPPORT AP,
 TRANSPORT V
 where PP.BILL_NUMBER = DT.BILL_NUMBER
 and  PP.BILL_NUMBER = AP.BILL_NUMBER
 and DT.BILL_NUMBER = AP.BILL_NUMBER
 and AP.YEAR = DT.YEAR
 and PP.YEAR = DT.YEAR
 and PP.PRODUCT_NAME= AP.PRODUCT_NAME
 and PP.YEAR = 2017 and DT.YEAR = 2017 and AP.YEAR=2017
 and nvl(AP.BILL_STATUS,'0') not in ('D','I','R')
 and V.TRANSPORT_ID = DT.VESS_ID
 and   TRANSPORT_MODE != 'X'
 and (  (DT.ARRIVAL        between 
 to_date(to_char(&C_FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-RR')
                       and     
 to_date(to_char(&C_TO_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-RR')
 and nvl(AP.BILL_STATUS,'0') in ('U','S')
        )
 or ( TRANSFER_END between 
 to_date(to_char(&C_FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YY') ,'DD-MON-RR')
                       and     
 to_date(to_char(&C_TO_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-RR')
 and nvl(AP.BILL_STATUS,'0') in ('P','C','A')
        )
      )
 order by decode (AP.BILL_STATUS, 'U', DT.ARRIVAL
                              ,'S', DT.ARRIVAL
                                  , TRANSFER_DATE)
,decode (TRANSPORT_MODE,'B','1','T','2','P','3',TRANSPORT_MODE);
```

Comment: Am getting error at the below place:
           and ( ( DT.ARRIVAL          between
                                        *
ERROR at line 33:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line,

```
to_date(to_char(&C_TO_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-RR')
```

to

```
to_date(to_char(&C_TO_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-RR') ))
                                                 --  ^
```

You are really missing right parenthesis.

Comment: This is wrong. The matching brackets for the start of `(  (DT.ARRIVAL        between` are the two brackets before the `order by` clause.

Comment: I am using the to_date(to_char(&C_TO_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-RR') 
at two places
Should I need to Change it in two places or only at one place ?

Comment: @APC Please suggest the exact line where I need to make changes. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be the substitution variables. In SQL*Plus we need to treat date input as strings. So you need to quote the variables, like this:

```
to_date(to_char('&C_FROM_DATE','DD-MON-YY') ,'DD-MON-RR')
```

Which of course means you don't need the `to_char()`, so just this:

```
to_date('&C_FROM_DATE','DD-MON-RR')
```

---

Incidentally, at the time of writing it is **2017** so you really really really shouldn't be using the `RR` mask. Wean yourself off two-digit years otherwise you will [inevitably introduce corrupt data into your tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44514208/146325). Use:

```
to_date('&C_FROM_DATE','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Oracle will still allow you to enter two-digit years (the century defaults to the current one) but at least the intention is clear.

Comment: Incidentally, at the time of writing it is 2017 so you really really really shouldn't be using the RR mask. Wean yourself off two-digit years otherwise you will inevitably introduce corrupt data into your tables ----> You mean to say, I should remove the 'DD-MON-RR') Mask too from the query ?? Please correct me if i am wrong.....

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says : **TO_CHAR (datetime)** converts a datetime or interval value of **DATE**, **TIMESTAMP**, **TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE**, or **TIMESTAMP** WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE datatype to a value of VARCHAR2 datatype . Anyway as @APC said , you don't need **to_char(...)** function . If you write something likethis `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')` is correct , and you don't need additional pharentesis in your code , an example here : `select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;` .I want suggest to you,to escape to becoming crazy when you get kinds of errors like **right pharentesis missing** ,try to check the query and expressions you are writing many times ,executing the query while you are writing , not just at the end.